# Twitter Bootstrap table width full width but content centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table like this (included bootstrap):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>Head1</td><td>content1.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td>content1.2</td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td>content1.3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Head2</td><td>content2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Head3</td><td>content3</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the table lines over the full width of it's container but the two cells with header and content should be centered.. I've tried to describe it in an image:

I cant upload the image here, so I've done it somewhere else:

[image: See image for more description]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: tried to fix by width check out my answer below

Comment: There is only two columns already!

Comment: so what you want? you want four coloumns? let me know for this if yes then you can add two more td's in the below table and arrange it by width and this will work

Comment: Yeah if you want I need four columns but even then, how can I adjust the two empty extra columns to center my middle 2 columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have shown only two rows (`tr`). You can add as many rows as you want.

HTML:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Head1</td>
         <td>content1</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Head2</td>
         <td>content2</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>      
   </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.table.table-hover{ width:100%; }
table.table.table-hover tr td{ width:25% }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rhfZY/)

Hope you will find this useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you can try this let me know if you have any issue
**css**

```
.wid50{width:50%;}


<table class="table table-hover" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="wid50">Head1</td>
         <td class="wid50">content1.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>content1.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>content1.3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Head2</td>
        <td>content2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Head3</td>
        <td>content3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Note : Do not use `width` attribute, as it has been deprecated: the rules should be defined and styled using CSS. use the CSS property width instead.  read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: yeah we can do this by `css`

Comment: i answer two time because i can't understand what he wants that's why i put both condition in front of him

Answer (score 1):

Please check this also according to your image

```
<table class="table table-hover" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="wid2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="wid1">Head1</td>
        <td class="wid1">content1.1</td>
        <td class="wid2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>content1.2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>content1.3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Head2</td>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Head3</td>
        <td>content3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is css

```
table.table tr td{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
.wid1{width:20%;}
.wid2{width:30%;}
```

Comment: Thats cool, but can you modify it that the inner two columns are not fixed to 20%. I want them to be as large as the largest item in the column. And still the two middle columns should be centered.

Comment: i answer two time because i can't understand what he wants that's why i put both condition in front of him